# String concatenation with constants in ruby 2.7.2

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to concatenate a constant into a string but I'm getting `syntax error, unexpected unary+, expecting` end' (SyntaxError)`

This is an example of what I have to do:

```
NAME = "Jane"
def a_function
   s = 'Hi' + NAME +' !'
   puts s
end
```

I know you can do `"Hi #{NAME}!"` but in my case the string has to be with single quotes.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `s = 'Hi ' + NAME + ' !'`

Comment: _"the string has to be with single quotes"_ – may I ask why?

Comment: `'Hi'.concat(' ', NAME, ' !')` or `'Hi' << ' ' << NAME << ' !'` or `['Hi',NAME,'!'].join(' ')` or `'Hi %s !' % NAME` or `'Hi '' !'.insert(3,NAME) ` or `'Hi'.concat(32,NAME,32,33)`. [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#method-i-25)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a space between `+` and `' !'`.

This is a special case of confusing Ruby, because a single expression like `+x` is actually a valid unary expression meaning just `x`, the same way as `+1` means `1`.

Because of this it's likely Ruby is interpreting your expression `a + b +c`, as `a + b c`, which is invalid, and hence the error.

The fix:

```
s = 'Hi ' + NAME + ' !'
                  ^------ Note the space here!
```

Comment: I have been unsuccessful in my search for a Ruby doc that addresses this. Your answer would be improved if you could find one.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I give you a hint what I think it is, and see what you think about it: In Ruby you can only call a method WITHOUT args in parens, if the method call is not part of an expression. Hence `method 123` is valid and works and it means `method(123)`, but if you do `1 + method 123` it is NOT valid Ruby, because method calls inside expressions have always have arguments surrounded by parenthesis. So the only valid method call in an expression is `1 + method(123)`. This is why `a + b c` breaks. Ruby thinks `b` is a method, but there is no parenthesis, and hence it is invalid syntax.

Comment: @CarySwoveland See if you can find what the restrictions are on method calls without parenthesis args in the docs, and you may find the answer. If you figure it out from official sources it would be pretty cool.

Comment: @Casper *"So the only valid method call in an expression is 1 + method(123)"* is not exactly accurate as since `Integer#+` is actually a method call too so `1.+(meth 123)` is also valid. You can create odd expressions without parens that are still valid for example `arr=[1,2,3]; p arr.pop arr.shift + 1 #=> [2,3]` but remove the space between + and 1 and it's a `TypeError`

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, but you are adding parenthesis or other hints to the parser which helps it decide what your intentions are. I have written compilers and interpreters as part of my job previously. When you have a language which is as diverse as Ruby is, then parsing quickly becomes extremely complex. This is why small hints like parentheses or just rearranging expressions will give enough hints to the compiler about what you intended. What I am talking about here is EXPRESSION OPERAND EXPRESSION, in such a scenario, unless you add explicit hints, you cannot call a method without paren args.

Comment: In your `pop` example the parser is interpreting it as p(arr.pop(arr.shift + 1)). This is not a problem. But when you try to do `expression + any_method_call arg` it will fail. It might be a bug in Ruby. I don't know. It's also possible the situation is too complex to resolve unabiguously. We would need to read the source code of Ruby's `parse.y`. The answer is in that file, but it is huge. https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/parse.y

Comment: @CarySwoveland it is about operator precedence. Unary `+` has a higher precedence than addition. So in this expression `+' !'` is actually interpreted prior the rest of the expression resuming in what @Casper described as `a + b c`

Comment: Friendly ghost and @engineersmnky, got it! My problem was that I didn't understand why, when Ruby saw `+' !'`, she wouldn't conclude that `+` was addition because there is no `+` unary operator defined on strings. What I forgot was that one can create unary operators, which is why Ruby cannot make that assumption! For example, `class String; def +@; upcase; end; end #=> :+@`. then `+'cat' #=> "CAT"`.  Thus, `'Hi' + NAME +'cat'` becomes `'Hi' + NAME 'CAT'`, raising the exception. Casper, this and smnky's previous comment may be worth mentioning in your answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland or ruby core team can create one in 2.3  [`String#@+`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-2B-40)